# Did I diffrentiate correctly?

Tags: calculus

$$\dfrac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dθ}\dfrac{6\sin⁡(3θ)}{\cos^2(3θ)}=\dfrac{18\cos^3(3θ)+36\sin^2(3θ)\cos(3θ)}{\cos^4(3θ)}=18(\sec⁡(3θ)+2\tan^2(3θ)\sec⁡(3θ))$$

Did I get this right? wolfram gives me a different answer...

$$18 \sec^3(3θ)+18 \tan^2(3θ) \sec(3θ)$$

If somone can show me how this answer is received I'd be grateful, spent hours on it yesterday trying to figure out wolframs answer..I don't know where I'm going wrong, I used the quotient rule.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\dfrac{\sin3\theta}{\cos^23\theta}=\dfrac{\sin3\theta}{\cos3\theta}\cdot\dfrac1{\cos3\theta}=\tan3\theta\sec3\theta$$

$$\dfrac{d[\tan3\theta\sec3\theta]}{d\theta}=\dfrac{d[\tan3\theta]}{d\theta}\cdot\sec3\theta+\tan3\theta\cdot\dfrac{d[\sec3\theta]}{d\theta}=?$$

Comment: No worries (let's delete conversation)!

Comment: Thanks, I understand now..would my answer still be correct?

Comment: @Modrisco, Please your simplify your answer as $2\tan^2\theta=\tan^2\theta+\tan^2\theta$